# automatic delete token in userdefaults after 6 hours in swiftui

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, userdefaults

I have two apis

1. Login
2. DataShow

when i login server gives me **token** which remains valid for only **6 hours** and i am saving it in **userdefaults**, so that user will not have to login again and again

and when user **token expires** then it will show login page otherwise directly show the datashow page

can someone help me i need to find a way to **remove** then userdefaults token in 6 hours.

Comment: Tokens should not be stored in UserDefauls, it is the most insecure type of storage. Keychain is a better option.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on token's lifespan. You can do whatever you need to do after an unauthorized error from your server.

Answer (score 0):

For that You should get difference between time of Login and time of opening app again, if difference is greater than 6 Hours then empty you user default.

When user login save current date in User Default and when application Start call onAppear function and check difference between current date using following function.

```
  func hours(from date: Date) -> Int {
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: date, to: 
    self).hour ?? 0
  }
```

Then,

```
  if hours(from : loginTimeDate) > 5 {
     UserDefaults.standard.set("newvalue_or_Empty", forKey : "Your_Selected_Key")
  }
```

Hope This Might be Helpful.

**Update as Per Desdenova Comment : -**

Use this Function onAppear as well :

```
   func seconds(from date: Date) -> Int {
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: date, 
    to: self).second ?? 0
   }
```

This will give you seconds till you timeout of token. Then get this token and Set timer. Time Work while app is active.

```
   if hours(from : loginTimeDate) > 5 {
     UserDefaults.standard.set("newvalue_or_Empty", forKey : "Your_Selected_Key")
  } else {
     let timeinterval = (6*60*60) - seconds(from date: loginTimeDate)
     Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timeinterval, repeats: false) { timer in
         UserDefaults.standard.set("newvalue_or_Empty", forKey : "Your_Selected_Key")
         }
    }
```

Comment: This will break if the token times out when the app is active, or when user's time zone changes while traveling.